# Centralized key management for IOS and Android Code Signing

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, code-signing

What is the best way for an enterprise to manage code signing certificates?  The default seems to be that Apple and Android keys get stored by each developer on their machines.

I see systems like Amazon Key Management Service and Microsoft Key Vault that seem to be ideal for this, but I don't think that it is actually possible to use them for iOS and Android apps.  To me, it looks like the ideal way to handle this, would be that the code is submitted to a centralized key server, which signs the code for the developer, without ever revealing the private key to the developer.  Change developers, and you simply revoke their access to the key management server.  Then you also have one strategy to handle all of your various keys. It also seems easier to integrate with continuous delivery.

Is there any strategy that organizations use to manage their private keys for code signing both ios and android apps?

Comment: Why not just create a build server like Jenkins. Install the certs on that machine as a part of the build script, and only give the developer access to the input/output.

Comment: @Aron -- that helps.  I just thought that many enterprises would be using some more secure Keyvault/KSM/HSM style code signing process, and I'm surprised I've never heard of such a thing and can't find any details indicating that such a thing exists.

Comment: The reason you can't find it is because it doesn't exist as it would defeat the purpose of having a private key. Consider what signing actually means. It is proof that the code originated from you...

Comment: @Aron, of course signing is proof that it comes from your organization.  Which is why typically, for every single other cryptographic signing purpose except for some reason code signing, an organization will want to control access to the signing certificate through a keyvault........

Comment: Nope. Never seen anything of the sort. The point of chain of trust is that private keys souls never be transferred, only the public key. But the problem you have is that you expect to have to revoke that trust...

Comment: @Aron, I'm honestly not sure if I don't understand what you are saying, or if you don't understand what a key vault does.  With a key management server, nobody has access to the private key.  It is never transferred anywhere but resides only within the vault.  Your employees have access to instruct the machine to sign specific things, for a specific time period.  If the employee moves to a new team with different rights, they are no longer able to sign things.  An organization should _always_ assume they may need to revoke an employees rights to sign things on their behalf...

Comment: @Aron, I second what user1724280 says !   What you want is exactly the reason HSMs were invented !

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the iOS distribution certificates can be stored in AWS KMS?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116991)

Answer (score 1):

For iOS and OSX there are 'developer' certificates, needed to provision on up to 100 devices; and 'distribution' certificates, needed to upload to the appstores. The first is personal and is bound by a developer license. The latter could be reserved for your corporate build Mac. The 'team agent' can use it and upload, and delegate  rights. The distribution is the one to watch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an application signing tool which is stored securely which takes smart cards which contain the signing keys. The application signing tool (USB connected hardware which takes the smart card) can be stored separate to the smartcard. Developers and testers can test the application using dev/test keys but, once the application is ready for release, someone can perform the final signing under dual control, due to separate access to the above tools, and this can be released to Operations for deployment to production.

Comment: This might work perfectly for a small scale but @user1724280 has already mentioned he's looking for a more adopted , safe and secure solution.